# Inventory System won't update the Total Quantity using Visual Studio and MS Access

Tags: inventory

I am a student working on an Inventory System using Visual Basic and MS Access. I was able to save on the Invoice however it won't deduct to the Inventory Total_Quantity... There is no error message.

Here is the code :

```
Dim ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:"
        Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr)
        Dim Str As String
        Conn.Open()

        Str = "UPDATE [InventoryTable] SET [Total_Quantity] = [Total_Quantity] - " & TextBox8.Text & " WHERE [Item_Code] = " & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & ""
        Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Str, Conn)



        MsgBox("Saved")



        Conn.Close()
```

Comment: You are defining the command but not actually executing it. The next statement should be: `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I add its however the error that I am getting is "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: What are the values in TextBox8 and ComboBox1 ? You can use msgbox to display the final SQL statement. Leaving those two fields empty or merely using single quotes will result in broken SQL code. At the very least you need to validate the input before trying to update the database.

Comment: The TextBox8 is the quantity of items to be sold and the ComboBox1 is a list of Item_Codes that will be sold. User will input then the quantity on TextBox8 and select an Item_Code on ComboBox1 to be sold. This will deduct from the InventoryTable.

Comment: Yes, but are the values you inserted in those two fields ? Can you show the resulting SQL statement ?

Comment: All is ok now... I just put ' " " ' and thats it... sorry Im a noobie :-) Thanks for the reply